# Asite I can view that uses HTML/CSS and C# coding

Tags: c#

Hi I am just learning about C# can anyone recommend a site I can look at and look at the development side of the site to show me just how the C# language is applied to the site.  Eg. is it just added to the HTML like JS or how is it worked into the coding.  I just can't get my head around how it comes together with HTML, CSS and C#.
Thanks Linda

Answer (score 2):

Creating web applications with C# comes in 2 flavors. Web forms applications and MVC applications. Web forms is the oldest and was the first. It works based on events. You would design a form or a "page", drag controls onto the page (such as a text box or a button), then wire them up to do something based on some event. For example, if you had a button on your application, you would respond to the `Click` event. The events were server side and would cause a post back. After the post back, your event, such as `Click` would be executed. This code was in C#.

Because this event based program was cludgy and ugly and didn't really "flow" correctly with how web applications work, MVC came along. MVC (Model-View-Controller) works differently. When someone in their browser put in your URL (http://www.example.com), IIS would execute your controller that handles the page they are requesting. Your controller would optionally load data from a database, put it into a model, then pass the model to your view. The view is your UI and it receives data from the model and does "something". Any new web application you make these days will almost always be an MVC application.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks can you suggest a site that has been created using the MVC so I can look at how it was all makeup and fits together to get my head around it.  All the sites I have found use HTML CSS and JS not C# MVC

Comment: @LindaMitchell You will not be able to tell by looking at a site if it uses C# MVC.  All of the c# logic is used server side to render the page before sending it to the browser. For example, http://aresteamstore.com uses C# MVC

Answer (score 0):

Try the ASP.Net MVC framework.

http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/mvc_intro.asp is a good tutorial to get you started with using it.  It is slightly outdated, but still gives a good intro to how it integrates with HTML.